# Why do people take downvotes so personally?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

*In a land where imaginary Internet points exist -*

I have noticed a rash of "why was my question downvoted?" questions and it seems that in every case a small number of downvotes has caused the OP to rant first before someone on Meta can calm them down and get to the heart of helping to improve the OP's question(s).

Have we, as a society who gives trophies to everyone who participates, heightened the sensitivity of people to the point where any small take-away is construed as personal?

It makes me think that we should do something similar to what happens when a vote is cast for a duplicate answer - when a downvote occurs a community user comment is with a link to "how to ask" or a "there is an issue with your question" info page. I *know* that commenting on DV's flies in the face of several posts concerning being forced to comment on a DV but if there a generalized thing like I mention above it might not be so bad.

Comment: this is a psychology question. Off-topic and voting to migrate... just kidding. shesh! Well, let's see. Nobody likes to be called "stupid," it's a pain greater than any...

Comment: LOL! Great comment @Coffee Here is the thing, a `downvote !== calling someone stupid`

Comment: *We* know that, but that doesn't necessarily mean that everybody else does.

Comment: No matter how bad we may think a post is, I'm pretty certain each and every user feels their post is of value and has taken reasonable effort on their behalf. As anyone, they want help or just a pat on the back. When that doesn't happen ....

Comment: I know it is a psychological thing, but I don't understand why someone, especially if they have read all that they should before posting, would assume that a downvote is equated with stupidity @JonK

Comment: *"if they have read"* ... that's a pretty big if. And then there's the difference between theory and practice of "I welcome constructive criticism".

Comment: Well that's the thing, the overwhelming majority of users *don't* read all that they should have...if they did we would be seeing the tons of junk coming through every day, and they largely wouldn't need to whine about downvotes as a result

Comment: But I know it's more practical... to keep it exactly as is. It just 'feels' a little funny

Comment: A downvote can mean so many things...poorly worded question, incomplete question, failure to even try themselves, duplicate that could have been resolved with a simple search...etc.  Since there is no differentiation in a downvote, people tend to take it to mean they are wrong and not one of these possibilities.

Comment: A downvote is represented by -1. I think there will always be a negative stigma associated with negative numbers, it's just how it is.

Comment: Yeah, it's why I was so bad at math. Any time the answer was a negative value, I felt like it was telling me I was a complete failure. I don't even want to talk about how irrational numbers made me feel…

Comment: Sounds like you have some kind of complex.  I can only imagine...

Comment: Actually, the fact is that (1) people are insecure (because they are aware of their _competency_), (2) they take downvotes as a sign of being told that they are incompetent.  From times immemorial, truth has always caused grief to humans.

Comment: I very rarely take it personal, but sometimes it's anoying to see a downvote on a complete and IMHO correct answer. I've see sometimes a day or two in a row people downvoting perfectly good questions too.

Comment: The only time I take a downvote personally is when it seems it is done in spite, especially if I proved another user wrong and they used their downvote as a means to spite me, has happened before now. Any other time I will ask for a reason to downvote, since I wish to know why I am wrong so I too can learn; afterall that is the point of this site right, to learn from others knowledge? A anon downvote seems counter-productive to the sites purpose

Comment: @Sammaye +1: Although I agree with most statements that have been made here so far, one at least has to *consider* the possibility that sometimes, a downvote (by some people) is actually **meant** personally...

Comment: I was tempted to downvote this question just because you clearly don't care, but I couldn't because I actually agree with your sentiment.

Comment: Have a downvote!

Comment: @danizmax - sometimes a correct answer is not a good answer...for example, if a person was to ask a SQL question that could be answered in a single SQL statement, I will downvote potentially correct answers (and sometimes an accepted answer) that use a cursor simply because it's using a cursor and not a set based solution.  A correct answer and an ideal answer are often 2 seperate things.

Comment: Some teenager programmers think that the length of their penises is directly proportional to their score in whatever site or game they have some participation. They are also very concerned about the size of their penises, always seeking to maximize their scores. This mentality is just a phase - as they age they drop these ideas (usually).

Comment: @Sammaye This has already been discussed enough times. I'd say you should not ask people to explain their downvotes. I've seen these innocent inquiries, and been fooled by them quite a lot. Most people asking for downvote explanation are only looking to punish the offender, not to learn. If I explain the downvote, I only warrant myself angry comments, calling names, sometimes revenge downvotes.

Comment: @kapa If those people wish to punish then that is their choice, the downvoter knows what they could be getting into when they comment so they have control at all times; I personally prefer a different choice in life.

Comment: If a person is at wits end, and comes here for help, just to get down voted, it is a strong motivation to assume that people are just being elitist, rather than helpful, hence move on. I try to go out of my way to explain my down votes, because I am willing to reverse them, if the issue is corrected. Though I do not recommend changing the policy, I do encourage people to explain their down votes. It took me a while to lean how to write questions that didn't get down voted. Even now, I am still learning.

Comment: @Brian: agree, but there still is a huge gap between "being at wits end" and "plz show me teh codez need ASAP!!" Mainly in how you ask; and a good written question **will not be downvoted**.

Comment: @Jongware It might be downvoted, I have downvotes on my best answers. It happens. Still, I'm quite sure a good question will have much more upvotes than downvotes though.

Comment: @Jongware, true. But that goes the 2nd part, where I wish people had explained their down votes, like I do now.

Comment: @kapa in fact if a person reacts with verbal or assaultive behaviour when being explained a downvote I personally believe they should be classed as breaking the rules. In a public forum (forum being used to mean a place of any kind of discussion, including Q&A) you are expected to have respect and manners towards each other. So yeah if the OP/AP wishes to attack the downvoter I personally frown on it

Comment: @Sammaye I am a programmer. I am not wasting resources on something that does not work. Explaining downvotes is one of those. 90% of my downvote explanations do not result in an improved post. Half of the remaining 10% only improves it after some meaningless verbal fight. They might be breaking the rules, but that does not help me, I don't downvote and comment because I want to win something.

Comment: @kapa hmm, maybe I can explain a time where explaining a downvote might help me as a programmer to find an answer to problems in a better, more concise, manner potentially avoiding duplicates and wasting my time. One time is when you downvote a heavily upvoted answer that is in fact wrong (they do exist on this site, wasted my time on some). If you explained there I could have avoided wasting time. So itmay not change the post but it could help those who visit the question later

Comment: @Sammaye Of course I leave an explanation when I feel it is worth it. I did not say I never do it :).

Comment: Look at it this way:  I have 25K points.  It's been proven that offering bounties is useless, so the only "useful" thing you can do with them is downvote.  So the real question should be "Why did you NOT downvote my answer?"

Comment: related: [On large communities decaying over time, being nice or mean, and Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256003/on-large-communities-decaying-over-time-being-nice-or-mean-and-stack-overflow)

Comment: StackOverflow (et al) gamifies advice and wisdom. To be downvoted, either question or answer, is to be told that your contribution isn't a contribution, isn't valuable, or some other generic negative judgment. Without making any judgment specifically on you as a person, a downvote definitely expresses disapproval of your input, and naturally that's painful to people. I happen to think this is a crucial topic for the SO community to sort out. The culture around downvoting, especially retaliatory behavior, seems dangerously corrosive.

Comment: We can have a page with contents only being `downvote !== calling someone stupid` in large, friendly letters, and then automatically link it to downvoted posts?

Comment: Huh?  It seems I've been using downvotes wrong.  Do we need a new feature for "call OP stupid"?  :P

Comment: "Gold" in many online (World of Warcraft) games is just "imaginary points", and yet people pay real world money for it on eBay and farming sites.  Go figure.

Comment: see also: [How can we discourage over-downvoting on questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253227/how-can-we-discourage-over-downvoting-on-questions)

Comment: Many downvotes *seem* frivolous or even malicious. But it's not always just a perception; it's a fact of life that well-formed questions sometimes get downvoted for meta-reasons like being duplicates. This is especially frustrating when the asker could not have known the question was a duplicate because the answer involves concepts that the asker does not know the terminology for. I still hold the unpopular opinion that downvotes should be eliminated entirely and question scores should have a floor of zero. The site can be moderated entirely through close votes.

Comment: People take upvotes personally too but complain less.

Comment: Anyone suggesting that downvotes are somehow too painful to justify their existence should read these questions: [Is downvoting harmful and should it be removed completely?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405582); [Why are proposed changes to voting, which limit or remove the use of downvotes, met with strong disagreement?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405699/why-are-proposed-changes-to-voting-which-limit-or-remove-the-use-of-downvotes)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

> Why do people take downvotes so personally?

Two reasons:

1. It hurts to be told that you are wrong.
2. Downvotes lead to a ban.

The rep loss seems (mostly) a minor thing.

Comment: This. There are a lot of people out there who kick up a huge fuss over anything to do with rep, but to many other people, rep is totally irrelevant.

Comment: Downvoting doesn't tell someone they are wrong, it just indicates a problem with the question. I guess people misconstrue that too.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard: Even if we're talking about questions and not answers, you can be told, for example, that your *premise* is wrong. For example, I know I downvote questions like "which is faster, `class` or `interface`" because, I mean, seriously. In any case, I think when the answer says "to be told that you are wrong" it just means "to receive negative feedback" in general.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I mostly had answers in mind, but this is also true for questions. You indicate a problem with *their* question. This *precious* question that they feel proud of.

Comment: As a relatively new user, I know I find it a tad annoying when someone downvotes a question I've researched pretty thoroughly without telling me how to *improve* the question. I think that's where the personal element comes in - people feel criticized without understanding *why*.

Comment: http://xkcd.com/386/

Comment: I feel like another reason is that the downvoter is taking a -1 rep hit in order to force a -2 rep hit on the downvotee. So when your post is downvoted, not only did someone dislike it, someone disliked it enough to want to penalize you even though they had to take a penalty too. (Granted, both penalties are, as stated, in imaginary internet points, but still.)

Comment: @user000001 I would argue that your first point still holds even if the poster isn't particularly proud of their question/answer. It's still embarrassing.

Comment: But it isn't *penalization* @KyleStrand, it is a statement that there is something wrong with the question / answer.

Comment: Some people get banned from asking questions which frustrates them.

Comment: @MadsterMaddness some people keep reading crap again and again and again, and it frustrates them.

Comment: @JayBlanchard It's still penalization because you lose two points. The fact that that penalty is usually deserved doesn't make it not a penalty. Consider sports: yes, refs can sometimes make bad calls, but in general when you take a penalty, you probably deserve it.

Comment: It is not penalization because some is written that is isn't. Ha! Of course it is to a 30 or 40 rep user, not matter what is written. They could take that easier if they were given a reason and also if there were not so many jumping on the wagon. And by deleting the question they'd lose any chance to get an answer.  OTOH I think answerers take DVs easier because they (usually) have been around longer; unless they feel they get molested by some fanatic..

Comment: @BoltClock: The downvotes I hate the **most** are the ones which result from other people telling me my premise is wrong, when in reality they could just go ahead and answer the question trusting me that I know what I'm doing.

Comment: @user000001 it hurts to be told you are wrong especially when you are actually right and some idiot downvotes you because he thinks you are wrong, however his proof that you are wrong is faulty.

Comment: @Wow: If it just one person, others will likely upvote, when they realize the truth. You can also edit your post to better explain why the criticism is misguided.

Comment: @user541686 - Some of the questions that annoy me most are the ones where the poster insists that they know what they are doing but it is clear from the Question that they asked that they don't.  (Questions like: how do I securely embed a secret key in my software.  Or how do I extract information from JSON using a regex.)

Comment: There is a very important third point besides the second: WHEN THE DOWNVOTE IS CLEARLY FOR NO content REASON. This may seem subjective but there are some cases where the question is nowhere to be found on a stackexchange platform and .............................(shows research etc etc)    and still get's downvoted within seconds. If then a dwonvoter doesn't even leave an improvement-comment, it fells to many like a random downvote, especially when it happens within seconds

Comment: And because of the lurking ban people people get more and more careful about what they ask. This may be good in one way but bad in many possible good questions not being asked (besides people sticking with their problem because neither search engines nor SO's search gives them an existing question or there is a similar question that is def. not the same but you know... And yes of course i came here because i just got downvoted several times and don't get why because e.g. my question was specifically about where to ask a certain kind of question which most definitely a part of what meta is for.

Answer (score 70):

The fallacy of big numbers plays a role again, a common meta problem.  Quantifying it a bit, SO gets over 8000 questions per day and over 10% of them get downvoted.  If only 1% of those downvoted questioners would complain on meta we would get 8 raging posts per day.  Heaven forbid, we're not even *close* to that.  Reality is that ~99.9% of the downvoted questions do *not* draw a complaint, surely because the poster knows why his question got downvoted.

Another perspective, a company like BMW gets 36.78 complaints about safety per 100,000 cars sold.  If we'd achieve the same statistic on handling questions we would get 20 raging posts per week.  BMW take note :)

Not sure it is worth to reason about why such a very small number of users complain.  Surely the Christmas Day effect is a factor.  Expecting a Lego set but getting ear-warmers instead.

Comment: @derp Congrats, you're now one of the only people complaining about people complaining about people complaining about downvotes! :P

Comment: Trivia (since I had it handy): in the past 365 days, 3030070 questions have been posted on Stack Overflow, of which 601595 have gotten at least one downvote. Needless to say, that's far greater than every question ever asked on all meta sites combined.

Comment: 20% feels very low, looking at the average quality of questions. Or maybe they always post the good ones when I'm not here :).

Comment: @kapa http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258699/2371861

Comment: @derp I am afraid even to ask what are you complaining about [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269461/why-do-people-take-downvotes-so-personally/269628#comment83627_269504) ...oops did I just complained

Comment: This isn't Twitter, so just spell the whole world "someone." I thought you were yelling the word "so." Six downvotes for you!

Comment: @bjb568 I understand that, but that does not mean that the average quality is higher than what the front page shows. When searching, I run into crap all the time too. Not putting the crap out to the window for everyone to see would be great, and would help the site look better, but we would still have crap everywhere inside.

Comment: @derp Quit complaining about turtles!

Comment: They can't, because 1 rep is not enough for asking on meta.

Comment: @user202729 it is is you link to your downvoted question.

Answer (score 53):

I think the reason is because everyone wants the pat on the head.  Everyone likes a good ole' "Atta-Boy".  A downvote says, "I don't agree.  No cookie for you."

Now, sometimes I have constructed what I felt was the perfect question.  I did my due diligence, I couldn't find an answer and I meticulously word a question that everyone will love.  A question so good that songs will be sung about it.  And it gets downvoted.  And I'm left thinking, "How could anyone possibly find fault here??"  And it stings a little, I won't lie.

The last piece of the puzzle is that some people do live and die by points.  Either they want them so they can gain privileges, or they need them to avoid a ban.  People have been known to "game" points, it's **that** important to them.  And downvotes remove those hard-earned points.

Comment: This. Especially paragraph 2. I think the biggest problem is one or more downvotes with out any comments even hinting as to what was done wrong.  I come here to solve problems and to learn, and a drive-by downvote does neither.

Comment: you should explain really well why you down voting and your name must associated with the down vote

Comment: @Jlouro: (1) People can vote on a post for just about any reason they like (short of fraud or obvious revenge), and SO explicitly supports that.  If i could downvote your comment because "really" is overused, for example, would knowing why i did it make the vote sting less, or more?  (2) Being told their ideas are wrong makes weird stuff happen in some people's heads.  You've never had some nutjob follow you around SO -- or take it outside, emailing you, or even calling you at work! -- to complain about a post you downvoted.  I can't support making that more possible by removing anonymity.

Comment: I agree with you, but you must take some responsibility for your down vote, and honestly most of the down votes I recently see in SO should be further explained because they do not make sense, some are even plain arrogant.
Personally I dont care, it just makes me see if I can improve the question, or anser, if I see it stupid, I just ignore the vote.
I am not here for the Stats, I am here for the help, and I have had a lot here.

Comment: @Jlouro: No, I need not "take responsibility" for any vote i cast.  Votes are anonymous, and for a number of good reasons -- not least of which is so that less confrontational people have a say, and can't be bullied into retracting their downvotes.  (Yes, it happens.  People get attached to their internet points.)  And note that it's always the downvotes where people are getting all butthurt and demanding "responsibility" and other such BS.   I've never once seen anyone demanding that i account for every time i upvote.

Comment: If there were a way to comment anonymously, i might *suggest* that people *consider* explaining their vote.  But it'll never be feasible to require it, and i'd be against any system that publicly attached names to votes.

Comment: Yup, this is important: Different people interpret downvotes differently, maybe SO should even communicate it's meaning more. Only considering the people who downvote for reasons other than *dont like that profile pic* ;) or *havin a bad day*: There seem to be many people who see a downvote as a **this doesn't belong here**, while others, like me, see it as a **this question is so bad there is no reason it should be here and there is nothing i can do to make it better**, while others obviously are on another side of many. That way the feeling you get from a downvote changes dramatically as wel

Answer (score 26):

> why was my question downvoted?

It is good to note that not all questions that ask this are ranting.

It should not be instantly assumed the person wants a fight but even when the OP/AP asks without wanting a fight it can sometimes come through as looking for one.

Anon downvotes will always draw the most anger. I mean the first thing that will run through a persons mind is: "How can I be wrong,". And when they cannot see their mistake: "No, they must be wrong". Anon downvoting actually increases the anger of an individual in many cases (which I have seen personally).

I regularly ask this question when my answer/question gets downvoted, in fact I always will unless I can spot what's wrong; which if I could why would I post it (duh)?

I ask this question since I wish to learn. If I have a misconception or I have done something wrong I like to know. I personally hate anon downvotes since I have no idea what is wrong, and sometimes that is worse than actually being told you are wrong, especially if you think you are right or the downvoter has a misconception/misread themselves (can and has happened to me).

Sometimes it is as simple as me misunderstanding or misreading at which point when notified about it I can instantly act to delete/edit.

I mean, one of the main points of this site's purpose is to learn from others in a community spirit and sometimes an anon downvote contradicts what some have come to expect when they read about this site and its core values, since with an anon downvote the knowledge remains with the downvoter. It never passes to the community.

So when donvotes fly there can somtimes be anger, even if not intended.

It takes a very experienced and calm person to talk about a downvote on their own question/answer without resorting to "WTF".

As a general thought outside of this meta question: I personally think it is better to ask first and then downvote as a last resort. However, many (not all) downvoters find that annoying and won't bother to impart their knowledge or don't want to get involed in the long and sticky process that comes after which can result in 30 odd comments.

In fact when threads like this devolve into hate you may find it comes from anon downvoters who have posted answes and questions downvoted since they hate those people as they hate themselves for their bad mindset to downvoting. Kind of like wheel of hate really.

Comment: Why do you get angry from an anonymous downvote? That's the real question. **Why do people take downvotes so personally?** That was the OP. This does not seem like an answer to me. I doubt you are so zealous to learn that you get mad whenever a chance is taken from you :).

Comment: @kapa Indeed since the question had been answered quite well by user0001 I decidedto addsomething new instead of reiterating his answer since this reply is normally used on anon downvotes

Comment: @kapa "I doubt you are so zealous to learn that you get mad whenever a chance is taken from you" what do you mean? If you mean: "I am sure you get mad", hell yeah, in fact I have explained slightly why I can get annoyed, however, I would like to think all my convos about downvotes have been civil however, I can easily see how others would not be

Comment: I don't see anything new. You are just reiterating something that appears all the time on Meta whenever the word "downvote" is mentioned somewhere. Yours is one of the three answers here (not to mention the comments) that complain about anonymous downvotes.

Comment: You admit you get angry from anonymous downvotes. I say it's not because you want to learn so badly, but because your ego got hurt.  Don't worry, it's normal.

Comment: @kapa You are more than free to believe that, I personally think you are seeing something sinister that does not exist, however, that is your choice

Comment: I don't get angry when someone I don't know presses a button that does not exist, thus lowering a score that does not exist either. I have no problem with my choice :).

Comment: @kapa if the button does not exist howcan it be pressed?

Answer (score 10):

You think you contribute to Stack Overflow (meta, whatever) by posting an answer volunteering information you think a lot of people in the discussion don't have. Then your answer gets downvoted because people disagree with what you say. That feels bad. It doesn't feel like people appreciate the time you put in answering the question.

Comment: Do you feel bad when someone disagrees with you in a normal conversation?

Comment: @JayBlanchard It's not only disagreement, also "lack of appreciation".

Comment: @JayBlanchard, in a normal conversation, people who disagree tend to say *why* (otherwise people who disagree without any argumentation tend to be considered obnonxious). Downvotes with and those without comments differ a lot in that respect, on SO.

Comment: How do you know that there is a lack of appreciation @BartoszKP? Just because someone disagrees with you doesn't mean they don't appreciate your point of view, question or answer.

Comment: I would have to say that folks are aware of the environment on SO @Bruno. You're not getting a conversation here, only questions and answers. In normal conversation I have said, "I disagree." and not had to offer any reasoning for it, nor was I considered obnoxious for not offering a reason for disagreement. I suppose that tone of voice would have a lot to do with that. (*How meta is it that I just disagreed with you?* ;) )

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'm not saying that there is. I only pointed out that your response to Christine's answer doesn't address the diagnosis as a whole so your analogy doesn't fit.

Comment: How so @BartoszKP? Even in conversation people put time and thought into their responses. If someone else disagrees with them they don't feel bad...it is just disagreement.

Comment: @JayBlanchard In conversation there is no *score* next to what you say implying judgement. I'd guess that can be the crucial difference :-)

Comment: I'll buy that for a dollar @BartoszKP!

Comment: @JayBlanchard Votes on SO and MSO are different, I was talking about the votes on SO. You were the one trying to make the comparison with a normal conversation (possibly implying that Christine's answer had something to do with her attitude to interactions with others in general, I suppose). From an answerer's point of view, if you've spent time trying to help someone with what you know (or think you know) and you get a downvote without comment, not being told *what* was wrong can be a bit frustrating, almost worse than being told "bad dog". Everyone can improve, *with appropriate feedback*.

Comment: I understand @Bruno and I am talking about SO (and a little bit about MSE). I have gotten downvotes for answers that I have provided - sometimes even when those answers were correct. I have gotten downvoted (and closed) questions. You're right - it is a little frustrating, but I don't take it personally. How could I? Someone clicking a button thousands of miles away doesn't know me and I don't know them. If they said something personally demoralizing in a comment that would be a horse of a different color.

Comment: I think one of the main things here is that SO is about right/wrong answer, that has mentioned many times, the downvote is a sign of accuracy and correctness not agreement. So I am not totally sure if this answer applies to SO personally

Comment: @Sammaye: Not only right&wrong. There can be many answers which are all correct, but we still value an answer with a story, a nice image, an example and concise but comprehensive rationale much higher than a simple no, or something somewhere in betweeen those two. (The second may even be subject to ultimate rejection: deletion)

Comment: @Deduplicator oh yes but if you follow the rules on how to post an answer then are you not downvoting because of preference not correctness/clarity?

Comment: @Sammaye People can downvote by preference if they wish. They can even downvote randomly, until they target a single person, that's not permitted. One downvote is not the end of the world. Do you always ask for an explanation on upvotes too? One could argue you could learn from that too. For some reason, nobody does that :).

Comment: @kapa sure, explanations on upvotes would be good too. I mean imagine answering "MongoDB is a in-memory data store", just read their homepage to know that's untrue, but it is near 10 upvotes.

Comment: @Sammaye: Sure, I generally don't judge those mid-spectrum answers downvote-worthy, though might withhold my upvote if there is a clearly superior answer, especially if that has fewer upvotes. Also, I try not to judge the answers too much on stylistic and ideological idiosyncracies (like ["best-practices"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354)).

Comment: @Deduplicator yeah that's totally understandable, only those worthyof an upvote should get one

Comment: I don't feel bad when someone disagrees with me. I do feel bad when people down vote my contributions. Like, when you post an answer on stackoverflow, an answer to a code question, you feel bad when your answer gets downvoted because that means people don't think you know what your talking about. Fortunately, my answers don't get downvoted on stackoverflow, just on metaoverflow.

Answer (score 10):

With regards to newcomers in particular, my theory is that Stack Overflow is sometimes mistaken for a social networking site.

One corollary of that is that downvotes are mistaken for "dislikes" which, as a rule, *are* personal - or at least tend to be accompanied with detailed explanations of just how much you suck.

If you're accustomed to this sort of environment, you may take the reason for a downvote for granted, whether or not any actual explanation is given.

Comment: So essentially [Jakob's Law](https://lawsofux.com/jakobs-law/): "Users spend most of their time on other sites. This means that users prefer your site to work the same way as all the other sites they already know."

Answer (score 10):

I think there is some [substitution bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute_substitution) playing here (no, I am not a psychologist but I see a pattern).

When you post a question, you expect to receive some help from the community.
Same goes with answers, you want to feel you contribute value - you invested some time to answer after all.

While the purpose of downvotes is to improve your answer and raise quality, people substitute the "I got a downvote; how can I make my question better and improve quality?" with "I got a downvote; community is rude - why are they so mean to me?".

This judgement is wrongly exaggerated when no constructive criticism is given in comments and goes against to what people expected in the first place, either when questioning or providing an answer.

Comment: It comes down, once again, to a [clash of expectations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377101/can-we-be-more-welcoming-by-managing-expectations).

Comment: It all comes down to [Jakob's Law](https://lawsofux.com/jakobs-law/): "Users spend most of their time on other sites. This means that users prefer your site to work the same way as all the other sites they already know."  

It's not a substitution. What this site does is to subvert people's expectations. If you have a GUI and use the floppy icon as the "delete everything" button people are going to have a bad time.   
 
You cannot fight against what people have already learned downvoting means. You cannot assign new meaning to a deeply established convention without friction.

Answer (score 7):

Aside from the other answers I think there is still one point not mentioned..**for improvement**

I don't post on Meta if I get a down vote but I do tend to ask on my answer what the reason for it was. By doing so it gives me a chance to see how I can improve and it gives the OP a better/clearer answer.

I tend to only disagree when I can't see any logical reason for the down vote. (This seems to mostly happen when every answer has a down vote except for one..)

Comment: *"I do tend to ask on my answer what the reason for it was"* Please don't do this. It just adds noise to your answer. Everyone who has downvote privileges has commenting privileges. If they wanted to leave a comment, they would have done so. No one needs you to ask them.

Comment: I agree, it would be great to be able that at least the first person to downvote *had* to pick a reason for doing so, so as to give feedback to the OP. If anonymity (or the lack thereof) is an issue, the comment can easily be assigned to "Community" or "anonymous" and that's it. Subsequent downvotes would not need select a new reason, though they could if they wished, and downvotes would translates to upvotes on the related "comment reason".

Comment: @CodyGray - In an ideal world, I would be inclined to agree with you. I do try to delete my request if feedback appears

Comment: @CodyGray: I understand what you are saying, however as the OP of a post, it is very frustrating to see that someone thinks something is wrong with your post.... but have no idea **why**.

Comment: @MatthieuM. That's been discussed and proposed before, and always been shot down as unrealistic. E.g. see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/267453/476 for a longer opinion of mine.

Comment: @deceze: I know, and yet...

Comment: Anonymity isn't the *only* issue, @Matthieu. The other problem is that it adds significant friction to the voting process, which would make people less likely to [down]-vote. We don't consider that to be a good thing, since both up and down votes are critical to the effectiveness of our post rating system. We seek to *encourage* votes, not discourage them.

Comment: @Sayse I very often find that the OP comments *seconds* after I have clicked the downvote button *"Why the downvote!?!"*, while I'm still *typing* my comment. Some people *are* a little too anxious.

Comment: I'm sympathetic to it being frustrating, but that is life. And especially the Internet. So just move on with your life. Don't clutter up the post with whining about downvotes. You aren't going to get the person who made an intentional decision *not* to explain their downvote to come back and explain it to you. You're just going to get some other well-meaning person to try and speculate on why someone else downvoted your post. And distract everyone else who reads your post. Please leave this out. If you insist on putting it in, it will be edited out.

Comment: @deceze - I usually wait 5 minutes+, any longer and there is a chance  the downvoter won't be returning. Cody, I don't dwell on it (and I also don't want this answer to be a feature request) but if there is an opportunity for improvement/learning, I'm going to take it. If I don't get a response, fair enough. This answer is also trying to address a reason why people would write a question on meta about a downvote, I would modify it but that would render these comments void.

Comment: @deceze - The solution is to make your comment before you downvote.

Comment: @HMcG The solution is for everyone to drink a big ol' cup of Calm The Hay Down. :o)

Comment: How about disallowing the first downvote on a sole answer without making a comment? It's not too bad if there's a downvote on one answer when there are other answers that have been well received, but it seems poor form, when there's only been one answer given, to downvote it without saying why.

Comment: I used to take downvotes really personally. I often asked for an explanation, and I always thought it's because I want to improve. It's not. People want to argue about it. They want an explanation because then they have someone to explain why their post is in fact good. I admit. Even if they improve their post, they do it for the removal of the downvote. Not for the improvement itself (very rare exceptions might exist, but they would do it even without being downvoted).

Comment: @chiastic-security: I suggested that easlier this year and got downvoted and, as I felt, pesonally attacked for it. By now the ratio on [that post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250177/require-a-comment-explaining-the-reason-for-the-first-downvote-on-a-question) is almost equal (+52-63); some, I have been told, simply __love__ to downvote..so nothing will be change. At the time I had decided to __never ever__ come to meta again. Well I still am rather reluctant, because is seems like one big waste of time. Enough!

Answer (score 6):

First, to clairfy, I don't think people take downvotes personally that much. Speaking for myself, I don't appreciate anonymous downvotes because they are counterproductive.

An anonymous downvote basically says: "you asked a bad question and I'm not even going to try to answer it or suggest an improvement." Or, for an answer, "you don't know what you are talking about." Maybe a person did ask a bad question. Maybe an answer is wrong. If a person feels the need to downvote, they could at least give a good reason why.

I think this brings up a more important issue: what is the purpose of a downvote? If it is just to be able to make an anonymous barb, then so be it. But if it is to provide some actual useful feedback for posters and viewers to judge the usefulness of a question or answer, then doing it anonymously is just pissy.

Comment: The whole idea of the gamification of SO is to use community moderation to make the content better.  Therefore points matter, whether the person with the points cares that much about them or not.  People with huge rep get privileges and are taken more seriously than people with low rep.  A down vote is a criticism.  You can criticize people constructively (edit, comment) or you can criticize people unconstructively (down vote).  When I see something worth saving I try to save it.  When I see something not worth saving I vote to close or flag it. I never down vote because it's just plain rude.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that most people who get upset over downvotes are confused about what downvotes mean.

I believe that Stack Overflow does not do a good job conveying its goal to people arriving here via a search engine (aka ~100% of people's first experience with the site).

Stack Overflow's goal is to curate a collection of the most well asked and thoroughly answered questions possible, without any clutter or distraction. It is an excellent resource for that reason.

It also differs in goal from basically every other technical support forum on earth. The goal is to enable research, rather than engage in one-on-one technical support conversations. More "What are the Best Practices or Mathematical Proofs or Evidence-Based Theories surrounding this general question", and less "what do I do in this specific situation?"

Because of its differing goals, it is a cold and difficult experience to engage with naively. Comments aren't allowed as a new user. Follow up questions are discouraged. Discussions in comments are discouraged. Comments are short and un-formattable. Downvotes are completely impenetrable as to "why". It's like rubbing your pet's face in urine and expecting it to stop peeing there. It just sucks and you don't understand why it is happening.

I think if users had a better understanding of what everything means and what the expectations are coming into the site from any other context, they would have a better time.

I think if there was an opportunity for discussion (perhaps an embedded Reddit-style comment tree attached to each question on the sidebar.) then users would have a much better time learning how to ask good questions. It is not hard to explain what Stack Exchange is meant to be. If you explain to people that a downvote means "This question is not up to Stack Exchange standards and needs revision", I think that people will take it much less personally, on average.

If they're not here to use Stack Exchange like it's meant to be used, that's okay, their question will just be lowered down in visibility once it's not "new", which works fine for literally everyone involved. They won't care enough to get angry, and people will still see their question and take a crack at it. If it's a simple question someone will give a quick answer for the fun of it, and if it's a difficult question someone can really dig into it and post/edit a more well structured question and answer that will get a lot of reputation. Win/win/win.

Comment: It comes down, [once again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269461/why-do-people-take-downvotes-so-personally/415184#comment887090_414980), to [a clash of expectations](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377101/can-we-be-more-welcoming-by-managing-expectations).

Comment: Yes, and I think a few UI/UX changes would reduce the problem considerable and make everyone have a better time on this site.

Answer (score 4):

The only problem I see with downvote is for new users. It's not very welcoming when your first question on this site isn't appreciated at all. Too often, those downvotes are left without any information to let the user know what's wrong. At the end, it might be a user that won't come back to ask question.

For other case, I agree with others answers. It could be hurting knowing your question/answer is not appreciated. After all, we should keep in mind that's only internet point.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't read all the answers and comments, but here's my take on this.
People actually want the reason for downvoting, at least I do. If I think that my question is well within the rule of SO and then I get downvoted, I need to know why? I don't really care about reputation, what I care is which part of my question is wrong? Have I done something wrong? If yes then what is the right way. I need to know how to frame proper questions so that I don't get a downvote the next time.

People need to post a comment telling why they downvoted a question. The reason should be stated there. That's what the warning ask us to do, as soon as we downvote. I agree that even I do downvote without posting a reason sometimes, since somebody else had posted it already or I am being too lazy. But when I am the OP I need the reason.

I suppose that's the reason people take it personally. Tell me the reason why I am wrong, I want to argue that I am right.

Comment: I agree with this.  In fact, I would suggest that down votes should have a reason the same way as close votes need to have a reason.  I understand the rationale for keeping down votes anonymous.  However, I think people would be _less_ likely to be upset (or maybe likely to be less upset?) if they actually understood the **nature** of the criticism that is being leveled at them.

Comment: @JoelBrown: In most cases, the reason for downvoting is blatantly obvious, if one reads the tooltip on the button, takes the tour, reads the [help] or looks at already present comments. Yes, it can be vexing not to understand a not explicitly explained downvote, but you do not want to have to explain your upvotes either, and voting - both up and especially down is - is critical for the system to work, so do not hinder it.

Comment: Devil's advocate: the warning ask us to "**consider**" adding a comment "**if**" we think the post can be improved.

Comment: @Deduplicator - I disagree that down voting reasons are obvious in most cases.  I am rarely, if ever, sure why one of my answers is down voted.  Also, with regard to the ease of up voting vs down voting, the system is not built on the premise that down voting and up voting be equally easy.  That's why up votes count 10 and down votes count -2 (and -1 for the voter).  I would argue that down voting is not at all critical, never mind "especially" critical for the system to work.  Voting to close is especially critical, down voting as currently constructed is counter-productive in my view.

Comment: @JoelBrown: There's a suggestion to make answer-downvotes free as well, because that one negative point stings, and many are too sensitive. Also, the reputation-effect on the post-author is not skewed because down-votes are less important or too easy, but because presumably the poster will learn. Next, how do you get a consistent abuser of SO banned if you reject downvotes as "not happy-making"?  The main purpose of votes is quality-control: Making the good stuff float to the top and pushing the bad stuff to oblivion, as well as removing those who are net-negative contributors.

Comment: @Deduplicator - I'm not suggesting that we reject down votes.  I'm suggesting that they need to be made more constructive.  If down votes were only applied for "this is wrong" or "this is shoddy" then that would be fine.  But down votes can just as easily be applied for "I'd do it another way" which is not a valid criticism.  If you'd do it another way, then write that as an answer and let people vote on it, don't drive-by down vote.

Comment: I agree with Joel on this. Downvotes doesn't always have an obvious reason. I don't consider myself as a SO pro, but I still get downvotes on questions and answers despite spending more than 2 years here. And most of the times it's not obvious at all. I had to ask in comments why it got downvoted, then someone explains and I correct the mistake or remove the post completely.
I'd vote for a feature which let us give reasons for downvotes, just like the close vote, without adding a comment on the post. Just so the OP knows where she's wrong. Better make it compulsory and remove the -1 penalty.

Answer (score -8):

It's certainly not about the rep; it wouldn't make any difference to me if there wasn't any rep loss whatsoever.

Sometimes I take them personally, sometimes I don't. It depends on the context.

#### For example: some types of downvotes that drive me nuts include:

- [Pointless (and sometimes stubborn) nitpicking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18550850/541686)
- [Knee-jerk reactions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21101774/541686)
- [Bandwagon downvotes, often caused by the first person thinking the answer is obvious or trivial](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19371340/541686)
- [Totally-unexplained downvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7748182/541686)
- [Downvotes on self-answered questions that were clearly entirely meant to help other people, not me](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16721864/541686)

In general the downvotes I hate the most are the ones are the ones that scream YOU'RE WRONG when in reality people are downvoting because they prefer to dodge the question and instead answer a different question (for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6818063/541686)).

And sometimes people downvote my answers because they don't *like* them (e.g. because I'm encouraging something they think is a "bad" practice), when they prefer answers that don't actually answer the question (because they think they know better and the OP should take a different approach). I find these downvotes pretty annoying because they discourage people from finding out the answers to their questions and instead serve as a means to tell people that the downvoter knows better than them.

I don't mind being told I'm wrong when someone can actually *show* me why I'm *wrong*, but I do mind it when people just have no evidence or they're outright answering a different question entirely.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Best practices are slightly different from what I'm talking about. The type of scenario I'm talking about is when, for example, I suggest the user of an undocumented API, and people then downvote me because The Right Thing in Their Opinion is to avoid undocumented APIs, when in reality they don't know of a better alternative or when in reality their alternative has caveats that mine doesn't have (e.g. it isn't available on the current platform). It's extremely frustrating because it's not a matter of best practice, it's a matter of getting the job done.

Comment: _bad practice:_  Yes.  This is very annoying.  It happens to me too often that I give a nuanced answer to a complex situation and some rookie ideologue armed with his rules of thumb comes along and tells me that I'm wrong because I'm not following "the rules", regardless of the fact that they themselves don't understand why those rules were put in place.

Comment: I am confused by your examples. In regards to nitpicking, you *accuse* the user of nitpicking, but they are commenting that your example *did not work*. That's a pretty big nit. In regards to "bandwagon votes because they *think* it is obvious", yes. I would agree that "you can not divide by zero" is pretty obvious. A quick google of the reported error tells me this, so in this case, I *would/have* vote*d* for "shows no research effort", which is pretty accurate. In regards to "self answered questions meant to help other people", your answer clearly states that you *forgot* something.

Comment: In regards to the later, you should consider how you phrase such answers. I immediately assumed that you posted the question, and soon after found the seemingly small mistake. *Then I looked at the time stamps*. Not many people would consider looking at the time stamps, too which it is clear the answer was posted *along with* the question. In general, it *looks* like another case of "shows no research". I would phrase such questions *without* any form of implication that you arrived at the solution *after* the question.

Answer (score -11):

One has to sign-in to participate to Stack Overflow, and then he or she has a nice profile page, with an *About* description, and perhaps a pretty picture. Also cool  badges. And, clearly the most important part, a reputation. Those points, while imaginary, denote effort in writing questions and answers and are real, because they mean time, concentration and passion.

So it is undeniable that Stack Overflow has a human meaning for posters.

As many in the comments have well expressed, it is annoying, depressing or demotivating when one spends time to write a question or an answer and gets welcomed by a cold reply, that superficially could mean "I don't like your post, and possibly others will not as well", but on the poster side, it could mean "My effort, time and passion just don't have value for the people I am seeing as experts and to whom I am asking for help", or in other words "I am not valuable as a member of the largest Internet programmers community". (This applies mostly to downvotes without declared reasons, i.e., anonymous.)

Since the OP question is mainly psychological, consider this: a small child has no value for their own family. They are just a "sink", they "drain" resources from their parents, sisters and brothers. However, in any sane family, they are not seen as a weight. Now, the child goes to their parent and says "look at what I have built", or "I have a *serious* problem", and imagine the parent answering: "it sucks" or "you are just a child".

While it is true, that Stack Overflow is for adults, psychologically we are also children. If not, we would never joke with co-workers, never get frustrated, bored, etc... always knowing the right answers and questions, and when not, admitting it for the good of others.

So, if (at least one) people (sometimes!) feel hurt by the system of Stack Overflow, there may very well be a reason. The answer should not be "take it or leave it", if it is true that the system is made *for all*. Some people are more sensible than others, some more insecure, some people may come to Stack Overflow because they have an urgent problem or a problem they have spent days solving it without success, some may just seek a word of advice from good programmers from a very well renowned Internet website...

Upvotes may flatter, no-votes may leave things are they are, and downvotes may give some minor or not so minor pain.

So I do not understand why they are there. Algorithmically, they may give better results, but humanly they are not optimal. But, is Stack Overflow for machines or for humans?

In Stack Overflow, other than technical research there are underlying human values and interactions.

Anyone seeing their values betrayed gets annoyed or depressed by the interaction with *other people* through the website.
I am not saying to give sugar for everything one does, but I am saying that algorithms and rules may kill the human relations if one is too rigid about them, and a website or software is rigid by nature. So rules should be minimal and acceptable by *all*, under the majority of circumstances.

What harm would do if downvotes were prohibited? Just upvote interesting posts and ignore the ones you do not like. Are out there really so few readers of Stack Overflow so that just upvotes are not enough to push up interesting questions and answers?

About "giving a signal to posters", votes alone are not a satisfying mean to "give a signal", as many say in the comments. Really, does a voter care about the person on the other side? They have not even seen the other, do not even know if they hate or love what the other loves or hates, nor do they know to what degree the questioner has need for an answer to their -- even vague but perhaps important -- problem. Truth is that one votes up or down based on personal tastes, ideas and beliefs. The voter cannot really care about the other, because the other is just a name and a pure product of thought on Internet forums. Even though it is true that the voter cares, when a child learns from an adult, they learn because they trust the adult, not because the majority of adult people give "correct" downvotes and upvotes. A child is not an AI that learns with punishments and rewards, they have feelings. So we are too, and a comment of 100 characters would be exponentially better than "a signal". As well, a *dialog*, where the poster and the voter talk to each other, would be even better.

Back to the initial observation, if Stack Overflow refrained from having a profile and a reputation for its users for giving them human (intangible) rewards and, just for example, limited itself on counting points on (anonymous) questions and answers, clearly the problem of being down-voted would not have been felt so much. One may say that a user profile *motivates* people to do better, but be aware that applying rules for one's own happiness without caring about the happiness of others, may be spelled as "gaming, manipulating, and using others", even if the end result is a "better product for humanity". Note, indeed, that if a great part of the population would be exterminated, much of the world problems would be resolved: overpopulation, poverty, pollution, ... A game is cool if everyone has fun playing in it. It is very important to *respect all others*.

Finally, note that readers volunteering to review posts do not get paid, but also authors of questions and answers are not paid.
To me, it is a minor satisfaction that downvoters (just of answers) lose reputation. What is the gain? We both lost reputation.

So to answer the OP question, the problem rises because of a confusion of the identity of Stack Overflow. In part, it is a social Q&A website where you always find answers to your questions. In part, it is a game, with strict rules, so when you have a question or want to share an answer, you must be very careful. If the second part is more prevalent, wouldn't it be better to build a moderated wiki like [PlanetMath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PlanetMath)? Or, just have a higher barrier to entry to post questions and answers, so that one is not misguided: when participating, one is working for the site, not asking questions or answering for himself/herself, i.e., the platform is not neutral.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/405699/why-are-proposed-changes-to-voting-which-limit-or-remove-the-use-of-downvotes

Comment: Just upvote interesting posts and ignore the ones you do not like. The issue with this is signal to noise ratio. It is an intensely frustrating experience, to find the 1 post that you do want to engage with, among the 10 that are good but have already had everything covered, and hundreds and thousands of posts that are unclear or unanswerable. Or to search hundreds of misleading answers to find the one that actually answers your question. That is why we have moderation. The emotional effort of the answerer and the reader.

Comment: Yes one votes up on taste. But if the taste of the individuals in the group on average trends together, then the votes are likely to be similar to the taste of the reader, and they can e used as a signal that approximates likelyhood. Its not perfect, but its a lot better than random.

Comment: There is lots of garbage posted on a daily basis. Ignore garbage input because someone's feelings might be affected? How else should this garbage be handled then? Completely ignoring it does the whole community a disservice

Comment: I have a personal bias against authorities (and systems) in general, therefore I find E_net4thecurator and @user1937198 comments valuable: the current state of affair is like so, because nothing better has been found yet. However, the next question is: have the, surely many, alternatives to the current voting system been researched? A fantasy example: "only upvotes, weighted by reputation, possibly recursive weights like PageRank". Do SO designers and supporters base their beliefs on scientific research on the subject? SO has tons of data, alternative systems could be "simulated" with it.

Comment: Only upvotes is logically a bad idea, because it is incapable of differentiating bad (or even incorrect and dangerous) content from "meh" posts or posts which haven't received much attention.

Comment: And rest assured that the folks at Stack Overflow do look into data and they do research on voting. https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/07/23/the-loop-our-community-roadmap-for-q3-2020/

Comment: One important thing to think about how stackoverflow is who it was designed for. Stackoverflow system is based around the relative scale of the various groups. It assumes that there are far more seekers of information than there are those who can provide it. As such redundancies in the information transfer (duplicates), must be eliminated as that increases the amount of seekers satisfied for the same load on providers.

Comment: This assumption that there is more demand than supply is is viewed as indicating seeking must be prioritized to maximise exposure of those questions that can be most efficiently answered, and are not going to put off the providers, again to maximise transfer.

Comment: @E_net4thecurator If I am correct, they just did a survey with 1400 responses: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406791/downvotes-survey-results?cb=1
They did not analyze valid alternatives. 
user1937198 I understand that there is a reason for downvotes, but I still not believe it is the best system out of all possible systems. It works, and some losses are tolerable, but 1. only after reading here on meta I understand the "game" of Stack Overflow, i.e. it is not a simple Q&A site, 2. some valid alternative could be nicer to play

Comment: If you think there is a better alternative suggest it, I'd love to hear it. But saying they are bad on there own without a suggestion of an alternative way of solving those issues, is implied to be a comparison against a system that is just upvotes. So far stackoverflow's is the best system to stick for a large (>10k people) community in the last 3-4 decades. And just saying AI and ML will solve it isn't an answer (SO's meta community knows enough to see through that hype). The higher barrier to entry has been discussed before multiple times, and is generally argued as being elitist.

Comment: There is indeed *a lot* that could be changed or done (e.g., with the heaps of data as you mention), but any significant innovation would have to come from another company or organisation. We are already at two times [6-8](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) years. For instance, the learning part and the beginners part are obvious. Some challenges are handling Eternal September properly and avoid meta talk and meta information creeping in everywhere (like *"Asked 7 years, 4 months ago. Active today. Viewed 5k times"* at the top of this page).

Comment: cont' - For example, as beginners tend to ask the exact same questions, why couldn't there be an AI bot they could converse with *in the beginning* (without any of artefact surfacing at the public Internet, unless it is of very high quality or interest)? (Though it needs to have much higher IQ than the moderation bots on Quora that have effectively destroyed Quora.) Or a less ego-driven Stack Overflow, with more collaboration in answering. E.g., a group of, say, 5 people used to work well together on Stack Overflow could write some awesome answers, with a lower regard to reputation points.

Comment: @user1937198 I don't have a solution, I am answering to OP about why people get it personally, and highlighting that is not because they lack intelligence or sense of community. PageRank is not an AI/ML algorithm. The idea is: if I am voted by a person who got in the past votes, from people who got votes, etc... then my vote is better than a vote taken from a newcomer person. Perhaps votes should meaningful when restricted to the tags of the question: if you are not strong in a tag, your votes there count less. Note though, my proposed ideas are just for the sake of discussion.

Answer (score -16):

Posters do not get upset at the downvote but rather the bad product. Posters come to SO expecting to have their *problem* resolved. Instead they find a community trying to resolve their *question*: question too vague, question too specific, question lacks MWE, question poorly formatted, question not well researched, question context lacking...imagine if you went to the doctor and said you are having pain and the doctor mockingly asked you "but how does it hurt, have you even googled these symptoms? Did you try to let it get better or did you just rush to see me? I bet this happened only once you hypochondriac.

Add to this the fact that (1) the SO community is incredibly terse to the point of coming across as a German engineer and (2) the SO community will stubbornly deny being terse, and you got yourself one unhappy downvoted poster.

I find it absolutely astounding that so many people hate the downvoted feature yet it has not been removed yet. Just have an upvote and then normalize the scores

Comment: If you go to a doctor, just say "it hurts" and don't explain where it hurts or how the pain feels, then I would expect the doctor to tell you that it is impossible to diagnose your disease. If SO would be a conversation (or a forum), then I would expect the doctor to ask for more details. But SO is a Q&A site, not a forum. It is expected by askers that they ask a question that can be answered without a long back-and-forth in comments. Also note, that SO is not about one's specific problem. It is about describing problems and solutions in a way that it helps lots of people.

Comment: @bdl but the doctor would politely ask you to explain the problem. I read an answer on here today that started with "have your read this question (linked)?" The professional way would be to rephrase the question then link to it

Comment: @puk: If this really was an answer (and not a comment), then it should have never been posted. Always keep in mind that on SO it is never about your problem, it is always about creating a repository of good answers and questions. There is no point in rephrasing other answers. (If the other answer solves your problem it is even better to close your question as a duplicate).

Comment: @BDL I think SO is caught between a romantic dream (wanting to create a repository of good answers and questions, as you put it) and reality (having to solve poster's problems to ensure a large community). It is the large community, principally, that keeps people coming back and having their questions answered quickly. Without questions being answered, this would turn into a static database

Comment: How many doctors work for free?