# Placeholder Answers: Will update with answer soon!

Tags: discussion, answers, fastest-gun

*I searched around for a previous topic on this issue, but didn't find one.*

I'm seeing what I believe to be a growing trend among low-rep users who are attempting to answer anything and everything to build up their reputation. Some of these users open a question that they think they might be able to answer, and before working out a solution, they will post an answer with text similar to the following:

> I'm working on the solution and will update with answer soon.

I'm labeling this a **placeholder answer**.

This seems to be so they can register themselves as the *first* to answer a question, as if that gives them some right of claim to the answer.

### Why is this negative?

I believe this action discourages legitimate answers from being given for a question. When a user is browsing the Questions page, questions that have an answer already provided are clearly distinguished from those that do not. Believing that a question that already has an answer is not worth their time, an SO user who might have a a superior answer decides to move on. The exception here would be if the question was of significant interest.

As a couple other answers might trickle in, the placeholder answer will get updated to finally contain the answer.

In the best cases, the answer receives a couple of up-votes, but another answer posted before this placeholder answer was updated receives the bulk of up-votes and is rightfully accepted.

In the worst cases, I've seen these placeholder answers plagiarize another answer and bash the original poster of the answer while stating "I answered first". All of this is in some attempt to be the one to whom up-votes are awarded.

### What can be done?

I feel that this behavior is detrimental to the integrity of the site. I believe it discourages more qualified answers from being given. I want to know what options there are for combating such behavior.

- Should I deliver a downvote to the answer, even if it contains a
  correct answer after it is eventually updated?
- Should I flag the answer for moderator attention?
- Would moderators even act on users who consistently post answers before actually having an answer to submit?
- What other options are available besides being *beaten to the punch* again and again by inferior answers?

Comment: It wouldn't discourage me, and I'll downvote any such posts if I came across them. I'll flag em too as *Not An Answer*.

Comment: I'll also leave a comment explaining why I downvoted the post. Unless a *shockingly stellar* answer follows I'd not be inclined to take that downvote back.

Comment: Will comment on this later.

Comment: @MartijnPieters If I flag it as *Not An Answer* and then the user updates it with an answer before a moderator reviews it, will the moderator take action/investigate, or will they simply dismiss the flag?

Comment: @crush: Perhaps a custom flag is in order, but I'd hope the moderator looks at the comments on the post too.

Comment: @crush Possibly, although NAA flags aren't generally handled by moderators, they're handled by 2k+ users in a review queue, and so can often be handled *very* quickly.

Comment: As far as I know, only employees (and maybe even them only by manual db-inspection) can look at the 0-revision. That might be neccessary to see that pattern. Anyway, we should always act on the post as-is, whether brilliant or execrable. Giving all that, I'm not sure there's all that much which can and should be done. Especially if the post is transformed to an answer inside the first grace-period.

Comment: @Deduplicator *execrable* - Thanks for that gem; had to look that one up!

Comment: If you want to be mean to them you can edit the placeholder answers to prevent further grace-period edits, locking the placeholder in the public revision history.

Comment: "This seems to be so they can register themselves as the first to answer a question, as if that gives them some right of claim to the answer." Maybe not a claim to the answer, but there's at least one badge tied to the first answer.

Comment: I found this comment on a related meta.stackexchange.com post: *"@AaronBertrand One more thing I've seen going horribly wrong, is people flagging the placeholder answer as not an answer, moderator arriving after the full answer has been posted, and, since there aren't any evidence that the answer was not an answer initially, dismissing a valid (imho) flag. This has happened to me on ProgSE as a user (almost all of my declined flags) and as a moderator. –  Yannis"* which is what I fear will happen if I am to flag such answers.

Comment: @Servy: that's just common sense! I like that idea. Now all I need is someone trying this game out where I can see em.

Comment: @crush It's not the end of the world if the flags are declined.  There are no negative repercussions.

Comment: Simply downvote the answer and assume the user will learn from it because they probably dislike getting downvoted?

Comment: crush regarding concern about flagging in [meta-tag:grace-period], you can take a look at MSE discussion: [Make first draft of a new answer part of the permanent revision history](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138017/165773). @Servy there are negative repercussions: [flag suspension](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/165773)

Comment: @gnat Yes, I'm reading that one now. It's got quite a bit of information. Thanks!

Comment: I would downvote and *not* comment. Just because my time here on Meta has shown me that such *really* irritates the type of people who post these answers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The purpose of downvotes on an answer isn't to punish those who post wrong answers, or those who manipulate the system, or even those who richly deserve it.  It's so that future users of the site can compare the quality of different answers, as opined by the community.  They fail to serve their purpose accurately, if you use them as a punishment tool.  So your upvote or downvote should be based entirely on the quality of the answer; not on who posted it, whether they did anything devious while posting it, or even on how many edits it took to reach the final state of the answer.

Comment: @crush - where do you see the trend? I have not observed it in [tag:ssl], [tag:openssl] or [tag:crypto++], so I'm curious where its going on.

Comment: @DavidWallace I am fully aware of what upvotes normally are meant for. However, people are *also* entirely free to vote for their very own reasons and the understanding is that *over time* votes reflect post quality. I *normally* vote based on quality alone, but I reserve the right to also act to correct what I see as cheating. Remember that a user adding a placeholder answer is trying to gain an unfair advantage over those that post actual answers.

Comment: @jww I can only remember it happening in JavaScript/jQuery/PHP questions. It happens very often in jQuery questions. I can't remember ever seeing it in C++/Java/C# questions.

Comment: I am starting to hate your site. I put in a placeholder answer  because of the number of times I have spent my time writing out a long answer only for the question to be closed underneath me.

Now I just put one in place and it got 4 downvotes and closed whilst I was editing it.

Comment: @CashCow I've had questions get closed while I was writing an answer, so I know what you mean. However, I would contend that when that happens a) I shouldn't have been answering the question in the first place; or b) I should help the question asker figure out how to ask an appropriate question that won't get closed. Then, I can vote to reopen the question once it is fixed. Once it is reopened, I will already have an answer ready to post.

Comment: They are usually closed as duplicates. Those "vultures" who steal all the rep by answering questions within a minute also seem to know when they're dupes.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> Should I deliver a down vote to the answer, even if it contains a correct answer after it is eventually updated?

You can deliver a vote anytime you wish as long as it's applicable. If it's updated within the grace period not allowing you a chance to undo your vote, you could even leave your vote in as a way of telling them not to risk it again in the future (given [how strongly people react to downvotes in general](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269461/why-do-people-take-downvotes-so-personally/269463#269463)). Entirely up to you. The odds that someone would be able to flesh out their answer *from something useless* into something worth an upvote in such a short amount of time are minuscule at best anyway — you'd have better luck [actually answering the question as quickly as possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455768/why-do-browsers-think-this-div-tag-isnt-immediately-ended/5455770#comment6183271_5455770).

> Should I flag the answer for moderator attention?

If the answer consists of **nothing** other than "I'll post an answer soon" then feel free to flag it as not an answer. If it does contain something that could constitute an answer, I suggest calling them out on it and/or editing out the fluff instead.

Protip: if you don't have an answer to a question, wait until you do.

> Would moderators even act on users who consistently post answers before actually having an answer to submit?

People who *consistently* pull this nonsense? *Absolutely.* Users who post non-answers or bad answers in a deliberate attempt to claim first dibs on answers, etc are not playing fair, not to mention skirting our quality standards. This sort of behavior is totally grounds for moderator involvement.

Just be sure to tell us this specifically when you flag. Bonus points if you link to revision histories if you ever happen upon users who are habitually tardy enough to fall into that trap.

> What other options are available besides being beaten to the punch again and again by inferior answers?

Ehhh... I'll have to get back to you on this one.

Comment: Awesome to hear a long-time moderator's stance on this particular issue. Thanks!

Comment: @Bolt: Would you even know it started as NAA, if the poster worked hard in the grace-period, considering there woukd not be any revisions for a normal user to see?

Comment: @Deduplicator: We'll always look for evidence. If the evidence disappears before we get to it then sadly we'll have to dismiss with no action. But if, like I said, the user is tardy and only gets an edit in past the grace period then it'll be in the revision history. And if the same user keeps getting these flags from multiple users, that would of course merit closer investigation. Maybe even a watch.

Comment: If this is a problem, perhaps users with a certain rep should be able to lock and flag the place holder. Make it a privilege or a badge. Then, it would be easy to take action against users who are practicing it. Mods would still need to take the action, though. I can only say *"If this is a problem"* because I don't observe it in [tag:ssl], [tag:openssl] or [tag:crypto++].

Comment: For the last part, there's always getting beaten to the punch by superior answers.

Comment: @jww you can force a new revision if someone else than the OP comments on the post. (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/255867/364003)

Comment: I've put a really short answer when racing against close votes before. If you could see the entire history you see it growing over a period of as long as twenty minutes.