# How to handle critiques made in comments on my answers?

Tags: discussion, deleted-comments, answer-quality, fastest-gun

Today, I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39839585/4875631). It seemed like a simple issue, and in an effort to get it done quickly, I submitted an answer with the code and added, "This should be what you're looking for" (see the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39839657/revisions) here).

Within a minute, a comment was posted saying that I should expand my answer, to help future readers. While this comment was being made, I was already in the process of rewriting the top section of my answer to provide an explanation. I then replied to the comment, mentioning that they should give the answerer a few minutes before commenting, in order to give users a chance to improve their answer.

A moderator then added a comment, (while deleting my original comment), and stated that a user doesn't need to wait, and that I should hold off my answer until it's ready. While I disagree with that statement, the fact that they deleted my comment made the entire situation moot. I felt it like using their power to enforce their opinion.

In a discussion about this issue, something was brought up:

> If I know I have a work-in-progress answer going that will take 10 minutes (but the guy can chew on the top half while I tinker more), I always state something like "This is a work-in-progress answer I am editing" at the top

This would have been an awesome reply, and it would have encouraged me to do something similar in the future. Because my comment was deleted (In the middle of the discussion), people weren't even offered the chance to reply. Therein lies the issue that this post is about.

How, as the public, should we handle things like this? Do we create a Meta post and try to ping the original user to view it? It seemed like it was right to proceed with the discussion in the comments.

EDIT: This is not a duplicate, because while this discussion mentions FGITW and placeholder answers, this post is more about how the situation was handled by the mods, and how to approach this subject in the future. The act of placing the reply, deleting my original question, and follow-ups.

We've had positive comments in the replies below, and I think this post has done what it was set out to do.

---

The thread of (now deleted) comments, included for context:

[image]

And for posterity, the final few off-topic comments at the time this Meta post was made:

[image]

Comment: A "work in progress" banner is a nice idea, but as a normal user I don't really have the time to sit on an answer until you say you're done with it.  Jon Skeet admits to using this "post a quick answer and then edit" technique, and I've downvoted more than one of his posts for being "not fully baked."

Comment: Note that I will be removing the remaining few off-topic comments from the original answer, as they've been reproduced fully here.

Comment: I appreciate that it might seem frustrating and one-sided that I'm deleting our comments while we're actively posting back and forth, especially if you think that we're having an argument and that I'm "winning" by deleting your comments. This is why I advised you to bring the conversation to meta. Comments are not for extended discussion, they're not for *meta* discussion, and once they've been read by both of us there is no reason for them to keep existing. There is no reason for me to leave off-topic comments intact, this is just making future work for mods when they're inevitably flagged.

Comment: @meagar My issue is with simply, your reply. You directly stated "Nobody should wait to get..." etc. This whole situation would have been avoided with "I'm deleting off topic discussion here. If you wish to discuss issues with the site, please discuss on meta.". To me, replying in the manner you did: Contradicts what Robert Harvey posted in his answer below, and felt like a bit of one-sided censorship. I appreciate what you do, and I hope you understand where I'm coming from.

Comment: @FrankerZ I apologize, I can absolutely see how this would seem unnecessarily harsh and hypocritical from your point of you. In retrospect, I should have deleted the obsolete comments and moved on rather than get involved in the meta-debate itself. While I *do* stand by the content of my comment (people absolutely can request clarification of your answers the second they're posted), the manner in which I posted them was itself off-topic and an abuse of the commenting system, and I kew full well as I was commenting that my own comments were subject to deletion.

Comment: @FrankerZ  I tend to make said comments, knowing they are off-topic, simply *because* I am able to take the onus to clean them up immediately afterwards. My actions were not those of somebody trying to suppress your side of an argument, they were those of somebody who is *busy*, and finding a few minutes here and there during the work day to do some clean-up on Stack Overflow. In the future, I will try not to combine the two actions of comment clean-up and comment creation. Thanks for bringing this to meta, and I hope there are no hard feelings.

Comment: @meagar Sorry for how this whole situation has unraveled. Thanks for your continued dedication to the site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Placeholder Answers: Will update with answer soon!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269993/placeholder-answers-will-update-with-answer-soon)

Comment: ...wrt quick comment under "draft" "answer", quite a pity that not enough users know and use [this great trick to throttle FGITW gamers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289668/839601) yet

Comment: @gnat See my reply, as to why this is not a duplicate.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a forum, so there is no such thing as `in the middle of a discussion`.  There are no discussions here. If you've posted something incomplete or in progress, then you can expect to be called out on it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Just to clarify, I definitely do "quick answer and then edit" but I always *try* to make sure that even the quick answer is good enough to be useful. (And any time you disagree, I'm totally fine with you downvoting, of course.) I wouldn't want to be held up as an example excusing posting something which isn't already useful. (And I would never ask for a grace period before someone comments, either.)

Comment: @JonSkeet: Nor did I mean to imply that your quick answers are never useful.  They usually are. :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Righto - I think we're on the same page. Please carry on holding me (and others) to a high standard :)

Comment: I'm not sure why someone would think it's a good idea to sit and stare at low quality content and wait for it to maybe eventually improve instead of commenting/flagging it right away as they come across it. Nothing would ever hit the VLQ if everyone was sitting around waiting for it to get there. This whole "issue" is easily avoided by finished the answer before posting it.

Comment: Again guys, and I'm sad this turned into a whole downvoting ring because of the fact people disagree with my FGITW stance: This post is solely about a mod proactively deleting my opinion while posting their own opinions in response to criticism on my post. I'm happy with meager's response, and I think this will be avoided in the future.

Answer (score 16):

Comments only have two sanctioned purposes:

- Asking for post clarification, and
- Responding with post clarification.

That's it.  Any other use of comments subjects them to removal at any time.

Every single one of the comments posted (except for the original "A little more explanation would be helpful") had to do with meta site mechanics, and not with the post content.

Comment: A comment can do more than *just* ask for clarification.  It can also point out missing or otherwise problematic content in the post, or suggest an improvement.

Comment: I consider that "asking for clarification."

Comment: And even then once the clarification is done and edited into the post, even those are subject of deletion.

Comment: You just replied to the post yourself with "Meta discussion here." with a link to this post. Doesn't this contradict what you wrote in this answer?

Comment: @FrankerZ There is no contradiction. Nobody claimed that it is impossible to post meta comments, only that *such comments are subject to deletion*, and they were.

Comment: @FrankerZ: There are actually many exceptions ("Conversation moved to chat","Possible duplicate of..."), but none of them are relevant to this issue.

Comment: @meagar So how as we, the public, supposed to handle these situations? If he offered a suggestion to the post, and I wanted to offer my opinion, what's the best way I should handle this? Create a meta post (How will he be notified, that this is a discussion?)

Comment: @FrankerZ: I think you're overthinking this a bit.  First, not all issues warrant a meta discussion, though you're certainly welcome to post one anyway.  Second, most moderators will not delete comments that are clearly intended to move meta discussion off the main page.  I said that other uses subject comments to removal, not that they *will* be removed in all cases.

Comment: @FrankerZ: As to your specific situation, you could have just ignored the comment, posted as you saw fit, let your answer speak for itself, and none of this meta hulabaloo would have even arisen.  There's no rule that says you have to respond to every comment that someone directs at you.

Comment: ^-- (Almost always the correct approach)

Comment: @RobertHarvey He's directly criticizing my post. At the time I made the reply, the comment was still around, and I shouldn't feel like I need to suppress my opinion to something that was asked of me. If he disagreed, quick short discussion, and I would have moved on. Mod could have stepped in later, and deleted the irrelevant discussion if need be, and all would be swell. Deleting in the middle made this blow up a bit more.

Comment: @FrankerZ: Then perhaps you should grow a thicker skin.  There will never be any shortage of comments criticizing your posts.  Responding to each one individually seems... rather inefficient.

Comment: Adding to @RobertHarvey's comment, you could have ignored the comment, updated your answer, and then *flagged the comment as obsolete*, and it would have been cleaned up shortly.

Comment: @RobertHarvey As meager replied, my handling of the situation could have been better. I personally have been told that I should wait before responding to questions, and I personally have avoided "code only" comments until they hit the VLQ or a decent amount of time has passed, so in this case, I feel like the "tougher skin" comment was a bit out of place. I'm sufficiently satisfied with how the situation should be handled in the future, but I'm happy to see meagar's reply to the original question about his handling of the situation.

Answer (score 10):

> He claimed that the comment was "obsolete", but it felt like he was using his power to enforce his opinion, which I disagreed with.

As I said, your comment was a reply to a comment that *had been deleted by its author*.

When I came across your answer, it had an orphaned comment that *made no sense* because the comment it was replying to had already been removed, *and* you had addressed the comment by adding context to your answer. This is the very definition of an obsolete comment, the kind that is routinely flagged and cleaned up. Rather than waiting for somebody to flag it, I removed it as it was adding absolutely no value and *no longer even made sense*.

By way of example, this is the state that the comments were in when I came across them and decided there was no value in waiting for them to be flagged "obsolete":

[image]

Comment: Poor Meagar always gets into trouble somehow.

Answer (score 5):

The original comment by the other user become obsolete when the post was edited as it didn't apply any more.

The rest of the discussion, being a discussion over whether or not it's appropriate to post bad answers that should be immune from correct and valuable feedback since that feedback would result in a correct indication that the low quality answer is in fact of low quality, was simply off topic.  If you're interested in discussing this with the user, you're free to talk with them in chat, ask a relevant question on meta, etc.  You can even discuss it in comments if you want, but you run the risk of a mod deleting the *completely offtopic* comment chain if they happen to come across it (through a flag or otherwise).  It's just the risk you run of holding an off topic discussion in comments.