# Posting dummy answers to preserve the topmost answer - good or bad?

Tags: discussion

Just curious, looks like a legal cheat when I see guys posting some rubbish dummy code and then quickly editing it over and over again, but staying on top of the list. Not sure if this practice encouraged by community or not, but doesn't the quality come first?

Comment: See [Placeholder Answers: Will update with answer soon!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269993/placeholder-answers-will-update-with-answer-soon)

Comment: Immediately downvote, flag as not an answer. That'll discourage these bozos soon enough.

Comment: "but doesn't the quality come first" - A thousand times yes. But that simple fact does not automatically persuade all people that stumble onto the site and immediately start to use it any way they please.

Comment: @Pekka웃 you forgot to [recommend posting a quick comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289668/839601 "as explained here") to trigger ending of grace period. So that if they edit the abuse will still stay clearly visible in answer revisions and voter will have a chance to retract and recover lost rep (preferably much later, so the downvote will keep abuser's answer score low for a while). Additionally, if one uses VLQ flag instead of NAA, edits will trigger a second downvote from Community user, making it even more painful for [meta-tag:fastest-gun] abusers

Comment: One problem I have with posting a long and detailed answer (read: one which takes a while to compose) is that there are FGITW posters putting short answers up while I am typing away, and then after I've pressed "Post", it will look like I'm just taking their answer and expanding on it a bit. Whereas if I would have posted my TLDR first and then edited to add in the details, examples, links etc, it would be clear that the concept was indeed mine to begin with.

Comment: @MrLister, the issue isn't with posting a `TL;DR` first. You can definitely post the short version of your answer, then take time to expand it. This has the added advantage of allowing the OP to try the fix while you're writing and then come back and see it explained if they're having any further issues. The issue in the original question is when people put `rubbish dummy code`, eg. something that really isn't an answer, something that just fills space and holds their place while they write the answer, is the discouraged behavior.