# Is it allowed to use an answer as a temporary additional space for comments?

Tags: discussion

Today I have stumbled upon [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63017159/5366641), which says at the very beginning:

> I don't got your question really, but a comment is not enough, I need some more space (please don't downvote).

The content has indeed clarification nature, so my action was to flag it as a *Not an answer* and leave a comment to the poster:

> Stack Overflow is not a bulletin board. Please do not post a clarification request as an answer!

First, my flag was disputed. Furthermore, the OP commented:

> The answer is used to discuss it temporarily and will delete it later

I would like to know, in order to react accordingly in the future:

Is it allowed to use an answer in such a way?

Comment: I would say no. If comments aren't enough to get a question in an answerable state then the question should be closed and the OP should do their part to clarify. We're not going to open up the answer textbox for other purposes then to answer the question. We're not a tutoring site.

Comment: Well, there you have the reason for your disputed flag: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/26744630

Comment: You are absolutely correct in brining this here and in flagging it as NAA. We have a [consensus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer/265553#265553) on when an answer should be flagged NAA, and this answer clearly falls under "Asking for clarifications" article. As far as I know, there was no shift in opinions, so the reviewers acted against best practice. Answers "under construction" can be drafted in GitLab [insert your poison of choice here] and should not be posted in that state. If it becomes one, sure, let's leave it, but alas...

Comment: And, btw, it is starting to spiral out of control, as the OP is already trying to find those who downvoted - this may lead to a series of revenge downvotes, so please, tread carefully - I would ask for a moderator intervention if it heats up further

Comment: @rene, thank you for the helpful explanation. I do not get one thing though - the reviews are way earlier than the question has been edited. Or you mean that the reviewers did not get into the details? In any case, thank you once again!

Comment: @OlegValter, thank you for pointing out the post about _what (not) to flag_! It is a great summary on the topic.

Comment: @scopchanov - the reviewers probably saw what they thought looked like an answer and probably did not read the contents very carefully (happens a lot + this answer is kind of a tricky case), or they are of compassionate type, or were in a good mood today, or they actually thought that the OP will finish what they started. Re:not at all - I bookmark them regularly - the flagging expetience is somewhat confusing without these guidelines.

Comment: @OlegValter, the bookmarking is not my best side. Actually, once I have read this post, adopted some behavior model and then, to be completely honest, forgot about it. So, I was acting more on an intuition and at some point one ask him/herself - was I really supposed to do that? Anyway, the topic is already bookmarked and I hope as such it will stay longer before my eyes. Something like the plane's manual. Check it each and every time you are going to fly. :)

Comment: @scopchanov - yep, something like a plane manual :) Actually, now that I think about this, there is an old post that covers your case (albeit from a different perspective): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269993/placeholder-answers-will-update-with-answer-soon

Comment: @OlegValter, yes, that is similar. Altough I understand it more as an improvement attempt. I also try to improve my answers. Believe me or not, no matter how much I proof read my posts, I am able to find the errors once I hit the _post_ button.

Comment: @gnat, Thank you for pointing that out. However, I have mentioned, that I did flag the question, but the flag was disputed. This discussion does not consider such situation.

Comment: @scopchanov - I do get where you are coming from here - that was just a reference to a more clear-cut version of the issue at hand which this answer is sort of a special case of. Re:the comment above - don't mind it, this is a canned comment when somebody votes to "close as duplicate" so your question is linked to the original Q&A about NAA

Comment: the duplicate guidance applies, you just need to follow it thoroughly. One thing particularly worrying about your approach to using this flag is you based it only on what the post says "at the very beginning". That's definitely not enough because the rest of the post may still qualify as an answer and it is possible for reviewers to dispute flag if this is the case. It's a bit tricky and takes time to learn to use this flag only on unambigous cases and not just on some slippery parts of the post

Comment: @OlegValter, sorry, if I misunderstood something!

Comment: @gnat, _The content has indeed clarification nature_ I did read the whole post.

Comment: now that you mentioned it I rechecked the [full first version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/63017159/1) of the flagged post and to attentive reader it indeed looks pretty much as not an answer. My guess is, [reviewers of your flag](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/26744630) were seeing later, much edited vversion and because of that it was harder for them to tell for sure, especially after 2nd edit which included to the bottom something hinting at the attempt to answer

Comment: scopchanov, no worries, people still do tend to react back :) Btw, the answer is in a good shape now, but it was not in that shape several hours ago. @gnat ( *I started writing the comment before your clarification above, sorry* ) - answers should not be a work in progress, at least not span more than one day. When it was flagged, it was much closer to being NAA than it is now, which is exactly the problem with the answer - we are now actively discussing it here instead of the question being closed initially or clarified in the comments.

Comment: @OlegValter no disagreement from me here. A while ago I even wrote sort of "instruction" on [how I prefer to handle drafts like that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289668/839601) - it includes flagging as a part of recipe

Comment: @gnat and none from me, I saw your next comment as I was hitting "add" :) Yeah, a comment would likely be nicer (btw, thanks, + 1 bookmark). I can't blame anyone for going straight to flagging in this case, it surely seemed like the OP is going to axe anyone who will dare to vote or comment

Comment: flagging alone in cases like that is a bit risky @OlegValter because post that you see may be changed by stealth edits in [meta-tag:grace-period]. That's why I recommend commenting: it "locks" what you see and allows further referring it without fear of possible stealth editing. It is useful also that such lock makes it safe to downvote because you will have guaranteed opportunity to retract and save rep if the post is later edited into proper answer

Comment: Moment. Now I am confused. Together with flagging, I also did comment. I believe it is fair to let the poster know what one considers wrong.

Comment: When [I reviewed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/26744630) the post I saw it at [revision 4](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/63017159/4) which, to me, was clearly not an answer: it started with "*I don't got your question really, but a comment is not enough, I need some more space (please don't downvote).*" - and later said "*So my question is, where do you expect something to go wrong?*". Both were signals to me that the post wasn't an answer.

Comment: @gnat - true, I agree with you on that (it was over 13 hours in this case when the review started, afaik). Btw, what do you mean by "save rep"? Wai Ha Lee - and you were absolutely right to review as "recommend deletion" at that point.

Comment: @OlegValter by save rep I mean, in cases like that I always downvote the answer (and it costs me -1). Without commenting (or, more precisely without locking revision triggered by comment) I would hesitate because there would always be risk for author to stealth edit it to better shape so that I would stuck with locked downvote and lost -1 rep. Comments guarantee me that even if it is edited, no matter how fast, there will be new revision and respectively, an option for me to retract downvote and recover -1 rep. It may look minor but I downvote quite a lot of answers...

Comment: @WaiHaLee other reviewers could be confused by overall length of the post and maybe by pieces like"if you would for example add 3 chars, your class would be still binary compatible" (myself, I would never pick "Looks OK" there but oh well)

Comment: @gnat - that's an interesting procedure you described, thank you for explaining - I don't downvote on answers much (and usually on older ones), will keep that in mind

Answer (score 29, accepted):

No.  Answers are for answers.  If the question can't be answered or more clarification is needed, that implies that the question should be closed until the OP can edit the details in.  The person asking what is effectively a comment should decompose their comment to get at the heart of the question they have, which *seems* to be this.

> [W]here do you expect something to go wrong? Do you compile those classes with different headers / different versions of your assembly? What do you mean by adding?

That's plenty tiny to put into a comment box.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! _If the question can't be answered or more clarification is needed, that implies that the question should be closed_ I see it exactly that way.

Answer (score 3):

"Rhetorical questions" :

- How important is it really that a temporary comment be posted as an answer?
- Does it require a feature that is not available in a comment, like content extend / formatting features?
- How temporary will the the comment posted as an answer be?
- Are you able to survive a massive down voting over your answer?
- What about if the answer is accepted by the OP and you are not able to delete it?
- Are you interested in being awarded with the [disciplined](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/37/disciplined) badge?
- How frequently will you post these temporary comments as answers?
- Are you able to survive a post answer ban?

Comment: This should be a FAQ :) In all seriousness.

Comment: Due to a penalty on downvotes on answers, they are used very sparingly, so the points about downvoting and post ban are empty threats. I don't care about badge shaming, either, so that also misses the point.