# If a question is going to closed, can I post half answer with "Work in Progress"?

Tags: discussion, answers, scope, closed-questions

A few days ago I was writing an answer for a new question.

As I knew that the question was not good fit for SO, I was in a hurry as my answer was a big one. When I almost finished writing my answer and going to post it, a message appeared that the question is closed. This made me sad.

Can I post a half answer with "Work in Progress" for this type of question?

Comment: Besides the fact that you shouldn't have been answering anyhow (as others are pointing out), I don't really understand what the point of half an answer would be. If it is half of one, then it fails to be an answer anymore...

Comment: @Kayaman Oops, I didn't mean off-topic, I edited tge question.

Comment: Don't post an incomplete or placeholder answer with the intention to come back later and fill it out or correct it. Question closure is a normal site moderation activity and you're not in a race to beat the other SO users. If this happens a lot you should learn to pick better questions to answer.

Comment: Indeed, while the site is designed with gamification in mind (so yes, it will make you feel like you're in a race), the only thing you can win is virtual points. You also learn a lot more by reading than writing.

Comment: Sure, you can if you enjoy downvotes and delete votes, as well as comments telling you never to do that, along with the risk of a mod message if you keep posting stubs to bypass moderation mechanisms. If a question is going to be closed, that is a sign you shouldn't post an answer. The question may also be deleted at some point, so even if you somehow manage to survive downvotes, flags, comments, delete votes, and potential diamond mod intervention, the question itself risks deletion (automatic or manual), and your work disappears either way. Just don't

Comment: see also: [Placeholder Answers: Will update with answer soon!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269993/839601)

Comment: *"...As I knew that the question was not good fit for SO,..."* -- you should have stopped right there. If the Q is off-topic, then don't answer, partial or complete.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Please, please, please do not do this.

If you know a question is off-topic, do not post an answer, just flag for closure.

Do not answer questions that are not a "a good fit for the site".

This type of question needs to be closed so the author has a chance to edit them into shape, so they are actually fit to the site's guidelines. Posting answers to this type of questions pushes the wrong message to users posting unfit questions, and makes curation harder for those that want to remove off-topic content.

And do not post incomplete answers (or questions) intentionally. If a post is "a work in progress", it should not be posted at all.

Thanks.