# Is asking someone why they downvoted you, and if they can remove it acceptable?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

Recently, I posted an answer to a question, of which the author gave some very basic details, and I understand some users are [ESL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_as_a_second_or_foreign_language), and may not know exactly what they are doing, but nonetheless, I tried to *decipher* what they'd written, and wrote the answer to the best of what I understood to be, what they wanted.

A few hours after posting the question, the author commented that my solution wasn't what he/she was looking for, and commented *(again, very vaguely)*, what they wanted, I understood that what they were looking for wasn't particularly possible, and commented so.

My answer was downvoted for this, *(not the comment)*, but the post itself, now, the post was written well, I used proper english, included screenshots, code examples, the whole cake and all.

But, from what I'd imagine to be the author's frustration at being unable to complete his task, it got downvoted.

Is it acceptable if I ask a question along the lines of,

> @user, Can you remove the downvote on my answer, it was well written, despite having vague instruction, and I'm under the impression that it may help people with similar problems to what I interpreted yours to be. So, can you please remove it?

Is this acceptable? To ask a user to remove a downvote for an answer that wasn't the applicable solution? This is a website where everyone benefits off everybody else's questions, and if not asked, posts their own, I believe that even if my solution wasn't applicable to the author, it may be applicable to users with similar issues/questions.

I don't particularly want to seem similar to [these sort of people described here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269461/why-do-people-take-downvotes-so-personally). To be honest, I can regather rep by posting other questions, editing, etc. So it doesn't bother me, and I don't really care that I was "wrong", I just think the author should think about the other users potentially benefiting off his question, before downvoting the *only* answer.

So, I am I wrong to ask? Or, should I just deal with the author's lack of care for others and continue with my day?

Comment: @RetoKoradi Sorry, I missed that when writing the question. I answered a post by another user, he downvoted my answer, to put it simply.

Comment: "the author gave some very basic details [...] I tried to decipher what they'd written, and wrote the answer to the best of what I understood to be, what they wanted." - That's the problem right here. Next time you encounter a question that is similarily unclear, simply flag it for closure and move on (and downvote it once you hit 125 rep). Trying to decipher the question often just wastes your time, as you've figured out. Rather waste OPs time and get them to edit their question into shape.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based solely on your description here (because I have no further information), it sounds like the author didn't think that your answer *answered his question*, or was *a correct solution*.

Not to put too fine a point on it, but that's pretty much the A-1 primary reason for casting a downvote. I think you have the wrong end of the stick in saying that he "has no care for others". In fact, downvoting an answer that one thinks is not going to be helpful is itself helpful -- it lets others know that the post has been judged and found wanting.

(I should note at this point -- as Bradley already did -- that you can't know for certain that it was the asker who cast the downvote, unless he owns up to it.)

Now, it could be that the voter -- asker or not -- is entirely incorrect in this judgement. (Again, I have only your narration to go on.) If so, the post's score should eventually, over time, be corrected by others viewing the post and applying their positive judgements. I suggest being patient.

Another course of action that might suit you -- since your interest is in spreading this useful knowledge -- is to delete this answer, craft a question which matches your answer perfectly, and [post that along with the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking).*

I would recommend against trying to argue with an anonymous downvoter in comments, even if you *think* you know the voter's identity. It's not likely to be a productive use of your time.

---

*Just a warning, because self-answerers often trip over this: your question needs to be a real, top-notch question; it will be judged the same as any other question on the site.

Answer (score 9):

First, you have *no proof* that that particular user downvoted you (unless they revealed their vote, which it does not appear that they did). Because of that, I would refrain from *assuming* it was them. Askers rarely downvote their post's answers anyways.

You can always leave a comment like: "Would the downvoter care to comment? I'd like to learn what you found wrong with my post."

Sometimes it will get answered, other times it wont. Its life.

Total aside, if the question scope changed, I would *at least* include the updated information at the top of your answer if you haven't already. If someone read your post, and it clearly didn't answer the question (unfair as that is given that the question changed), they could have downvoted for that reason.

Comment: Emphasis on being constructive when attempting to engage a downvoter. If you sound even slightly confrontational you can expect more downvotes.