# Why was this question put on hold, and how would I disagree?

Tags: support, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31577229/can-someone-explain-this-c-code-to-me) may not be for everyone, but it received two answers which should have helped the OP.  But then, *six hours* later, it was put on hold.  I just don't see what this accomplishes -- it seems to me that the people who felt it was somehow "unanswerable" have been proved wrong by the fact that it did receive answers.

In the end I suppose this sort of thing comes down to opinion and consensus.  So my real question is, how would I go about registering a vote in the other direction, to vote against putting it on hold?  Before the put-on-hold vote is complete, how would I even see that the votes to put on hold are accumulating and might need counteracting?  Do these things require privileges I don't have yet?

Comment: Close / reopen votes are unlocked at 3,000 rep. There's no "keep open" or "keep closed" votes though.

Comment: It doesn't say "unanswerable" anywhere in the reason given for closing that question.

Comment: Stack Overflow is supposed to be a collection of questions that will be helpful to other users; I fail to see how explaining a giant chunk of code is on-topic and helpful to any other visitors to the site, *ever*

Comment: It may not be *"unclear"*, but it's definitively **too broad** - see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253894/3001761. What you have demonstrated here is the problem with *not closing questions fast enough*.

Comment: 'Can someone explain this C code to me?' has my mouse hovering over the downvote button almost immediately.  Such activity is just ditch-digging for very little reward to anyone except the OP.  If OP's are going to copy/paste code from textbooks and tutorial sites, or copy some other student's work before it's been debugged, I'm NOT going to touch it.  The OP can dig its own ditches with their debugger/logger.

Comment: see [How to ask “how to understand some code” questions](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/7514/31260)

Comment: Wow.  I am truly impressed.  Not only did my question here get downvoted to -8, but the original question I was asking about has now been expunged.  (I'd apologize to the OP for calling attention to it, if I remembered who it was.)  I knew this place was harsh, and ruthless in its discipline towards those who don't fit in with its consensus, but this is a stunningly blunt reminder.

Comment: [What is the meta effect?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269349/839601)

Comment: [Why do people take downvotes so personally?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269461/why-do-people-take-downvotes-so-personally)

Comment: @BSMP: Thank you for that nicely patronizing link; it's just the sort of thing I would expect in this thread.  Believe me, it's not the downvoting I'm taking personally, it's this site's entire attitude.  If you're curious I could explain exactly why people take these things personally, why this site's habits and tropes seem so capriciously brutal to many of its visitors, but since  there's no way for me to do that in Q&A format, since discussion is frowned upon, since it wouldn't be helping to build a high-quality repository of answered questions, I'm not going to bother.

Comment: You just said, _"Not only did my question here get downvoted to -8..."_. I pointed to the discussion on how people view down votes because it seemed relevant.

Comment: @SteveSummit except you're on meta, where discussion is actually encouraged. So go ahead dude. But yeah, as was pointed, coming with "this code does what?" is not a super good question. How will ANYONE find this and use it later on? What google/stack search terms would yield such a result and help people? Stack got VERY popular because it contained good answers and questions people search for OFTEN. Now that stack is more popular, we get more and more people who think that, since this site helped them, it's a help desk. It isn't.

Comment: @Patrice: If you're worried about the site becoming too crowded with people who don't understand what the site is for, don't worry, I'll likely be bowing out.  (But yes, I _do_ understand that SO does not want to be a help desk -- I just don't _like_ it.)

Comment: Stack Overflow is supposed to be a repository of Good On-Topic Questions and Good On-Topic Answers that are useful to programmers around the world, the OP getting their problem solved is just a side-effect. If a questions is not good (read: well written), on-topic or useful to programmers around the world, then it does not fit on Stack Overflow. The reason that close votes are used before delete votes is to give the OP a chance to edit their question into shape. <continued>

Comment: Questions will automatically be submitted to the reopen queue if they are edited after being closed, where they would be seen by 5 users voting on whether to reopen the question or leave it closed. If the OP votes to reopen their own question (possible at any reputation level) then the question is submitted to the reopen queue. These are all measures put in place to make sure that the OP is treated fairly and is given a fair chance to edit their question into shape.

Comment: @TZHX "There's no "keep open" or "keep closed" votes though." Sometimes I wish there would be, because otherwise it's always like a one way street and prolonges the way for edited and improved questions. In more than one case I had to wait until a question was one-way closed before initiating the one-way reopen voting process.

Answer (score 20):

The fact that a question has answers doesn't, in itself, mean that it's a good/useful Stack Overflow question. It means two people felt like answering it.

*(Aside:  I wouldn't really count [one of those two answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31577365/1324) as a point in this question's favor.)*

I've answered questions that I knew would be closed, because helping the OP was still worth it even though — as here — it was never going to be any kind of general-purpose, searchable, "re-usable" question.

What are the odds of someone searching for "Please explain this code" and wanting that particular program baby-stepped? What are the odds of someone searching for a specific idea or method in that code, and actually finding it, based on the title and wording of the question?

re: the second part, see [How do you reopen a closed question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question).