# 'Ask Question' button to header

Tags: feature-request, design, top-bar

Is it possible to move the 'Ask Question' button into the header?

Sometimes when I'm looking for an answer to my problem and cannot find the solution, I then want to ask my own question. I'm usually at the bottom of the page at this time and then have to scroll up to click the 'Ask Question' button. I even look up for the button, thinking it's there, then remember to scroll up to find it.

Comment: Hit the `home` key on your keyboard.... and please let's not make that topbar even moar crowded ...

Comment: What about people that don't know about the home key? I also don't know where the home key is on my keyboard? I'm using Windows OS.  I think it would be more user friendly though to have the button in the header for easier access.

Comment: @Pekka웃  I know what you saying, but the reality of SO is that most people come here to find solutions and have to ask questions. That's where it all starts, with the Question, then comes the Answer.  Maybe promote Answering in the header and also have Asking in the header in subtle manner.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_key

Comment: The vast majority use the site as a "read only" resource though.

Comment: @Pekka웃 True, but I think there is a greater percentage asking questions,l rather than answering them.

Comment: I agree - but many of those questions are duplicates or otherwise not useful for us. Which is why we don't want to encourage them too much.

Comment: ^^^[this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255592/839601) explains why what you ask for is rather opposite to how things should be

Comment: *"What about people that don't know about the home key?"* These people are probably not professional and enthusiast programmers.

Answer (score 2):

Disagree, on a philosophical basis.

As tests here on SO and elsewhere show, placement of UI elements influences behaviour. Asking questions should be the very very last resort after a long exhaustive search. It is not an action the site should encourage too much by shoving the option in users' faces at every moment.

If after a long, exhaustive search you finally come around to asking a question, scrolling up to the head of the current page is not too much to ask.

Comment: I would disagree. I think 1 would rather search for the answer than ask a question. People would do more searching, hoping to find their solution as it would be faster to get solve their issue. Most people know when answering a question, it could take a variable amount time to get to your answer, so browsing for a solution would come first.

Comment: Maybe that button should be at the bottom of the page. At least if people are at the bottom, they scrolled down - so there's a bigger chance they actually read existing answers.

Comment: I'm also not saying 'Shoving the button is users faces' I'm just saying make it easier to access. It's less stressful after a lengthy dead end search.  You also commented yourself in my Question, that most people use the site as a read only, so why would those people Ask Questions even if the button is in the header. They not going to simply click the button just because it's in the header. Also having it in the header would help them be aware that they can ask their own Question here on SO, rather than searching elsewhere on other sites.

Comment: "I think 1 would rather search for the answer than ask a question".... Looking at the influx of terribly easy questions we get asked on a daily basis,I would have to disagree there.

Comment: `I think 1 would rather search for the answer than ask a question.` that does not match the reality of the past 8 years on Stack Overflow.

Comment: "I think 1 ..." I think one should spell out the pronoun.