# Scared to ask questions here - advice please?

Tags: discussion

I'm a computer science student who has been using Stack Overflow for a while now to research issues I've been having. Unfortunately there are some specific questions I have that I either haven't found on Stack Overflow or am too worried about asking.

I feel like everyone here is a professional and knows so much, and I feel intimidated - especially since I know that bad questions can get downvoted and while I may try my best I might not be able to ask a question in the most professional way or may not fully follow guidelines. Like for example, due to my inexperience and lack of knowledge - I might ask a question that has been asked before, but may not realize it.

I have executive dysfunction, anxiety, [Asperger's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asperger_syndrome) and a lot of other mental health issues, and I always worry about screwing up and due to the nature of my mental health - it means I most likely will screw up. I feel like my questions are also just so freaking basic and stupid that I almost feel embarrassed to ask them :(

I'm really not sure exactly what to do - so I'm looking for some advice here. Please and thank you.

Comment: There is an entire page on how to ask a good question. That would be the best place to start. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Before using the tags please read the associated information, on the other hand your question is in an inappropriate place since when you have been pointed out it belongs to the target site so it should probably be migrated

Comment: Added meta tag @AvenDesta Desta and reading how to write good questions now dfundako. Sorry for the bad question :(

Comment: welp my first question and it already gets shut down and I can't even ask another question for two days... I honestly can't with this website, it's too much for my anxiety :(

Comment: Not sure if this will help you at all, but this is what I do: I read the tutorials, I search for answers on the internet like mad. If neither works I stare at it until my eyes are dry and I try and fail and keep trying. But.. I'll never ask a Question on Stack Overflow for the same reasons that you listed here. I only answer posts.

Comment: I would not recommend asking questions on Stack Overflow. Not everyone has to contribute here. If you don't feel confident in your abilities then simply delete the account and use the site anonymously. The goal of Stack Overflow is to help people find the information to common problems and avoid them asking the same question again. It's likely that your question already has an answer on Stack Overflow and you don't have to start a new topic. Posting good questions is a rather difficult task, try to avoid it if you can.

Comment: The question is closed because you have posted it in the wrong place. It belongs on [meta] and you asked in on Stack Overflow. If you want to become a contributor then you have to read all articles in [help] and get yourself familiarized with this website before posting anything. Jumping straight into asking questions is going to be a terrible experience for you.

Comment: The question isn't stupid.  It's been answered elsewhere though so don't let that leave a bad taste in your mouth.

Comment: it's not really a stupid question, it's just been answered before.

Comment: It would help if you could tell us if you read all the Help Center articles. Those are meant to give you an good starting point and if there is anything unclear from that we can see what further guidance is needed. Also know here on Meta we have stuff like [The question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and ofcourse the [meta-tag:faq] posts. And [there is an external site with info on down vote reasons](http://idownvotedbecau.se/)

Comment: thanks guys and also sorry - this has been quite a rough experience for me, I'm reading through all the comments rn - and trying to learn as much as I can. It is exhausting for me, but I hope I can get it right :( . So please bear with me if I take long to respond.

 I do do quite a bit of research to make sure I'm not asking the same question, but as evidenced by this question, I kinda suck at a lot of things. I'm trying my best, but I just can't sometimes. My mental health prevents me from doing basically anything. But I do have specific coding questions which I can't find the answer of :(

Comment: Everyone sucks at something they have no experience in. Don't feel special. I was really bad at this when I started.

Comment: Not wanting to send you to a different site but do know that not all questions fit on SO. I see you say you are a comp sci student, so maybe your questions are fine for [cs.se](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Also make sure you teach yourself how to use the [onsite search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) as a pro. That doesn't need skills, just practice. Search is awkward at times, that is why it need practice.

Comment: Do look at questions asked by other users that had quality issues and came to meta for advice how to fix their posts: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bquality-improvement%5D+%5Bspecific-question%5D+answers%3A1

Comment: Maybe not something that helps you directly with the questions you want to ask on SO but it might be worth to check out [this question on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334297/how-can-we-help-and-support-users-with-anxiety-in-the-context-of-stack-exchange).

Comment: Also relevant: [Should we be afraid to ask questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255517/11682469)

Comment: You should be aware that software development is characterized by extreme frustration that never goes away, no matter how skilled and experienced you become.  Too often, Hollywood portrays 'programmers' as gifted kids, able to knock out 'code' in minutes to save the day.  The drudgery of the ditch-digging that is the seemingly never-ending test/debug cycles is rarely portrayed.  Developers are not paid to write code, they are paid to get it all working well enough to sell, and it can be very disheartening at times:(

Comment: Don't take it personal. People only see a question, not *you*. Ask the same thing to someone personally and everything changes. As for search tips: nothing beats "site:stackoverflow.com <your topic>" in google.

Comment: Searching in existing answers *can* be ***extremely difficult and time-consuming***, including for basic/beginner questions that almost certainly *must* have been asked before in more than 12 years and [20,645,782 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions). It is a non-trivial task to find the right keywords (e.g., not to be overwhelmed by false positives).

Comment: This is the best piece of advice ever posted about asking questions on this site: https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/